# How to cancel or stop Google App Engine Cron Job

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I deployed an application to my Google App Engine that uses a CRON job. I followed [this](https://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/cron-job-on-google-app-engine-for-java/) Tutorial. It works fine, I could confirm it in my GAE console. In my Stackdriver logs I can also see that the CRON job is running.

But all changes that I made to my `cron.xml` file did not apply after I deployed my application again. I even deleted the `cron.xml` file and deployed my application again - no effect. I do not want that CRON job to exceed any quota.

1. Is there a way to cancel /disable / delete a CRON job from the GAE console?
2. Am I doing anything wrong to cancel the CRON job by modifying and deleting the `cron.xml` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *some* cases (in particular multi-service apps from my experience) simply uploading the app/service may not update the cron configuration automatically. Most likely because the cron config is not a service-level config, it's an app-level one, independent from a particular service.

Which is why there are commands specifically for deploying just the cron configuration. From [Uploading cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron#upload-cron):

> **Option 2: Upload only your cron updates**
>
> To update just the cron configuration without uploading the rest of
>   the application, run the following command:
>
> ```
> ./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh update_cron [YOUR_APP_DIR]
> ```

And right below that you have [Deleting all cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron#deleting_all_cron_jobs) - basically uploading an empty cron config file (as opposed to just deleting the file):

> To delete all cron jobs:
>
> - Edit the contents of the cron.xml file to:
>
>   ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   <cronentries/>
>   ```
> - [Upload the `cron.xml` file to App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron#upload-cron).

Comment: Thank you, Dan. Your "Option 2" led me to the right way. My development machine is Windows, so I used the command in ./appengine-java-sdk/ directory: "AppCfg -A [My_APP_ID] -V [MY_VERSION] update_cron [PATH_TO_BUILT_PROJECT]". This was only successfull when there is a cron.xml file that has an empty cronentries-ag (like mentioned above) - it surprisingly did NOT work when I deleted the entire cron.xml

Answer (score 16):

Now with the gcloud tool it's a little bit [different](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#deleting_cron_jobs):

1 - set proper project:

> `gcloud config set project my-project`

2 - create a file cron.yaml with the following content `cron:`

3 - upload the new cron file

> `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml`

Comment: It seems that an empty cron.yaml gives this error: "ERROR: gcloud crashed (MalformedCronfigurationFile): Empty cron configuration." so I think you should add at least "cron:" as content and then to re-deploy.

Answer (score 1):

A few versions later, using `Google Cloud SDK 301.0.0`, `cron.xml` does not deploy as expected. Cloud Scheduler is the present standard.

The reference page explains how to [delete all cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron#deleting_all_cron_jobs).
Unfortunately, `xml` format of `cron` file is not supported by the mandatory *deprecated* `appCfg` tool.

To remove the existing cron jobs, the following was needed:

- install app-engine-java (`gcloud install app-engine-java`)
- as found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/downloading-application#troubleshooting), move to directory where appCfg lives
- create a file name `cron.yaml` containing the word `cron:` (i.e. no cron jobs)
- deploy the empty file like [documented](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron#upload-cron) using `update_cron` and the path to the empty `cron` `yaml` file.
- login prompt through browser could occur.

All cron jobs should disappear.