# How do I disable GCP App Engine Cron Jobs?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, cron

I have an old Java (Maven) App Engine application in GCP and want to disable the "App Engine Cron Jobs"

Changes to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/cron.xml are ignored by the appengine-api-1.0-sdk (1.9.86) maven plugin (although deploys are otherwise fine)

With reference to [How to cancel or stop Google App Engine Cron Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492050/how-to-cancel-or-stop-google-app-engine-cron-job), using `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml` only affects the "Scheduler Jobs" and I am unable to use the appcfg.sh (appengine-java-sdk-1.9.64) as authentication attempts to use a non-existent URL.

Any advice or pointers would be very welcome.

Attempted to use `mvn appengine:deploy` with com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk (1.9.86) but that does nothing to the cron

Attempted to use `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml` only affects the "Scheduler Jobs

Attepted to use `appcfg.sh update_cron [YOUR_APP_DIR]` (1.9.64) but that is referencing a non-existent URL for authentication

Comment: My only answer is to redeploy the `cron.yaml` file. But obviously it does not work and it's almost impossible to reproduce your case. A ticket to Google Cloud support is the most suitable solution!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by upgrading to the latest version of the cloud cli, then  gcloud app deploy cron.yaml worked.